# My objects will not move, only "orange" cursor moves when I try movement by the axis

Tags: objects, edit-mode, transforms, 3d-cursor, transform-orientation

I wanted to know if anyone could help me with this problem. I only can move the little "orange ball", not my object. in the workspace settings  I selected the "affect only" and checked all three boxes and its seems to move the "orange ball" and object in the opposite direction of each other. The 3d cursor stays put. Is there some setting I missed?

Comment: Well... yeah... you selected affect only origins so now it affects only the origin. Just untick the box and you can move your mesh normally. The orange circle is the origin of the object, the point which everything rotates around and which symmetry modifiers like mirror use as their origin point.

Comment: nvm that didn't solve the issue.  when I open blender under the default settings, If try to move a  object. only the orange gizmo moves, the object stays put